# Using Custom Adapter with CursorLoader

Tags: android, baseadapter, custom-adapter, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to use `CursorLoader` to fetch data from my `ContentProvider` off the UI thread. I then use it to populate my list view. I was using `SimpleCursorAdapter` before and it works all fine. But now I want to have different views for the list view rows depending upon the data.

So I wrote a ***custom adapter*** extending the ***base adapter***.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Log.d("CustomAdapter", "Check" + i + 1);
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_text_layout, viewGroup, false);
            //if(text) load text view
            //else load image view
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

But to get anything to display, the `getCount()` method should return a value greater than `0`.

How can I get the number of items loaded by the `CursorLoader` so that all elements be displayed? Currently, I'm just returning `10` to make it work but that's obviously not the right way to do it.

Here's my `Fragment` class which implements `CursorLoader`:

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private AbsListView mListView;
    private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(MESSAGES_LOADER, null, this);

        // Set the adapter
        mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        String[] projection = {MessageEntry._ID, MessageEntry.MESSAGE_DATA, MessageEntry.MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP};

        switch (i) {
            case MESSAGES_LOADER:
                return new CursorLoader(
                        getActivity(),
                        Uri.parse("content://com.rubberduck.dummy.provider/messages"),
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, in my `getView()` method, I need to access the data so that I can select which layout to inflate. I know we can pass a List of the data to the ***Custom Adapter***, but how do we do it when the data is actually loaded by `CursorLoader`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of extending `BaseAdapter`, you could extend `CursorAdapter`.

When `onLoadFinished` is called you only need to call `swapCursor`. You don't need to override `getCount()`. The `super` already takes care of returning the correct value.

Comment: A class which extends CursorAdapter expects a Cursor object while instantiation. Where should I instantiate my CustomCursorAdapter class then? Should I do it in the onLoadFinished() function?

Comment: instantiate the adapter `onCreateView` like you are doing it now, passing `null` for the cursor. Store the reference in a class member. When onLoadFinished is called, call `mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)`

Answer (score 0):

[`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) with [`ViewBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) set or [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) is enough to meet your requirements from what I see, you do not need to extend `BaseAdapter`.

Once you initialize the loader via `LoaderManager`, you will get the results via `onLoadFinished()` method.

To refresh the data call `swapCursor()` method on the adapter

Please note also that the `Activity` starts all registered loaders in `onStart()` so the alternative place to launch your loader would be in `onActivityCreated()`.

This tutorial describes the way which @Blackbelt and I are describing:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-properly-loading-data--mobile-5673

Once you dive deeper into loaders I suggest reading the article:

http://chalup.github.io/blog/2014/06/12/android-loaders/